# Can't create JavaFX project within Netbeans on Linux

Tags: linux, netbeans, javafx

so I'm struggling with this issue quite a while now. I want to create a new JavaFX project within Netbeans, but I don't have the option to choose JavaFX from the list. Since I have the most recent java version, JavaFX should be included in the SDK right? I also looked up if I have the `jfxrt.jar` in the directory `/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext` and I do. So how comes that I can't create a regular JavaFX project? Am I missing out on something?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have the latest netbeans?  it should be working.

Comment: I have Netbeans 8.1, not the newest 8.2. Do you think that's the issue?

Comment: No, it works in 8.1, go to tools->plugins and on the installed tab you should have JavaFX 2 support and JavaFX 2 SceneBuilder activated.  If not, actvivate them.  If they're not there, go to available tab and install them.  If you haven't messed around with these settings before to break this, maybe you downloaded a version for html or C ?

Comment: Ok I tried searching them in the available tab since it's not installed or activated. But if I search for them, I don't get any results. Like no results at all, no matter what I type in. I'm sure that I didn't install the wrong version since I can create java projects normally.

Comment: I figured it out by myself, had wrong settings. Now everything works. Thank you very much for your help @brian !

Answer (score 1):

For those who are also having the same problem (can't find JAVAFX plugin(s) in the 'Installed' tab, see @Fabian comment answer):

1. Go to 'Settings' tab (in Tools -> Plugins)
2. Check both boxes 'Certified Plugins' and 'Netbeans Distribution'.
3. Go to 'Available Plugins' and press 'Check for Newest'.
4. You should see JAVAFX plugin(s).
5. Install them and restart your IDE.